# Err_Name_Not_resolved in Webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to develop a web app that connects to a www.office.com from there Calendar using a WebView. I can reach the site but when I press the SIGN IN button, I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error. I also get an error in Chrome on the simulation. (This site can't be reached). How can i get through this error.?

My code is here:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
webView.loadUrl("https://www.office.com/?");
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> add permission in minifest.

Comment: I did it. No problem connect to internet and office.com. I can't do the next step. When I press the sign in button, I get the error and I have same problem on the chrome. I get error "This site can't be reached" when I press the SIGN IN button.

Comment: i check your code and its work for me when sign in button press

Comment: How is it works. I generate the apk version, and install my phone. It didn't works. Where is my mistake? Similator or gradle vs. ??

Comment: I check it mobile device and i used    minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26 gradle . Strudio  2.3.3

Comment: All are same as mine, Is there a way that I can get to your project ?